# What's the order of the two events with "until"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions

I don't quite understand an answer from the other site:

> But if the time expires **until** the process releases the spinlock, the process is moved to the waiting state, allowing ...

So is that the time expiration happen after the process releases something? Or is that the time expiration happen **at** the time the process releases something? (Or the others)

OK, I just watch [a video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHt2aqzUtYI) says `A until B` means `A` will stop when `B` happen, which make me more confused. That the `if the time expires` is not a period of time, it's an instant, right? how can this "instant event" ***keep happening*** until something happen? LoL

So how should I interpret the sentence?

Comment: The use of *until* is wrong. I suspect that if you replace it with *before*, the sentence will have the intended meaning. But I can't know for sure what the author intended to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example could also be read as (assuming the sentence is broken up badly)

> 1) If the time expires
>   2) **until** the process releases the spinlock (*and the process has not released the spinlock*)
>   3) the process is moved to a waiting state (*until the spinlock is released*)

Comment: Oh, I understand it, it's three steps.

Comment: Thank you so so much! This makes perfect sense now!